# Which calculus textbook is aligned the most with the CollegeBoard course description?

Tags: calculus, textbooks

The CollegeBoard website lists many [AP calculus BC references](http://www.collegeboard.com/html/apcourseaudit/courses/calculus_bc_textbook_list.html).

But it also mentions that "The materials on this List range in alignment from 59% to 100%."

So, which of them is aligned the most with the college board specification of the AP calculus?

Comment: I suspect they want to avoid an appearance of endorsing any one of them.

Comment: Actually, it appears that the third-party reviewer wants you to sign up to their service to receive the detailed information. _These materials have been reviewed by Learning List, an independent instructional materials review service for schools and districts. ... Learning List's detailed alignment reports identify the specific LOs and Practices to which each material is and is not aligned to help teachers use these materials more effectively. Contact Learning List for more information._ (links removed)